# How do I make this dropdown category correspond with my other dropdown category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched and dug and found questions with answers that I thought were going to help, but never did. 
 
I just cannot get this to work. I have already asked a question regarding this issue and I was directed elsewhere and still no dice.

```
        <br>Make:<br>
        <select id="make" name="make" required>
            <option value="default">Select make...</option>
            <option class="alfaRomeo" value="alfaRomeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
            <option class="abarth" value="abarth">Abarth</option>
            <option class="astonMartin" value="astonMartin">Aston Martin</option>
            <option class="audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option class="ford" value="ford">Ford</option>
        </select><br>

        <br>Model:<br>
        <select id="model" name="model" required>
            <option value="default">Select Model...</option>
            <!--ALFA ROMEO-->
            <option value="4cSpider" class="selectors alfaRomeo">4C Spider</option>
            <option value="4c" class="selectors alfaRomeo">4C</option>
            <option value="giulQuad" class="selectors alfaRomeo">Giulietta Quadrifoglio Verde</option>
            <option value="giulietta" class="selectors alfaRomeo">Giulietta</option>
            <option value="mitoQuad" class="selectors alfaRomeo">MiTo Quadrifoglio</option>
            <option value="mito" class="selectors alfaRomeo">MiTo</option>
            <!--FORD-->
            <option value="focus" class="selectors ford">Focus</option>
            <option value="f350" class="selectors ford">F-350</option>
        </select><br>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {    
                var allOptions = $('#model option')
                $('#make').change(function () {
                    $('#model option').remove()
                    var classN = $('#make option:selected').prop('class');
                    var opts = allOptions.filter('.' + classN);
                    $.each(opts, function (i, j) {
                        $(j).appendTo('#model');
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not just the typo here is it?

```
appendTo('#mdoel');
```

jQuery link to be added before this script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just fixed that and it turns out it only runs properly in JSfiddle. I can't run it from notepad in Chrome. Am I missing anything? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: is your jquery loaded properly in your notepad file? can I see your full file? you should have this or similar in the file before this script  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I thought that all I needed was a <script> //SOME CODE// </script>? Yeah, let me post the fiddle link.

Comment: Using   $(document).ready(function () {   means you're using the jquery library  so you need to include jquery. I'll update my answer to have the jquery hotlink - you may choose to bring it down locally

Comment: I should clarify - if you were using plain javascript you would not need the jquery library, but you're using lots of the functions from jQuery, so you definitely need that library loaded onto the page beforehand

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you! I've never had to do this before. I've been spoiled and made lazy by IDEs and web based smart editors.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to just show/hide options based on the class of the selected option in the `#make` select. However this will not work in IE since it doesn't support hiding `option` elements.

What you can do then is to clone original options and then append filted ones to the second select:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $model = $('#model');
    var allOptions = $('#model').find('option').clone();
    $('#make').change(function () {
        var classN = $(this).find('option:selected').prop('class');
        $model.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
        allOptions.filter('.' + classN).appendTo($model);
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/u1ah58jz/

Answer (score 1):

One solution here is to convert the options for the model to JSON data, then dynamically load the list when the make changes. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9endpLwc/).

```
<br>Make:<br>
<select id="make" name="make" required>
    <option value="default">Select make...</option>
    <option class="alfaRomeo" value="alfaRomeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option class="abarth" value="abarth">Abarth</option>
    <option class="astonMartin" value="astonMartin">Aston Martin</option>
    <option class="audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option class="arrinera" value="arrinera">Arrinera</option>
    <option class="acura" value="acura">Acura</option>
    <option class="ford" value="ford">Ford</option>
</select><br>

<br>Model:<br>
<select id="model" name="model" required>
    <option value="default">Select Model...</option>
</select><br>
```

And the script:

```
var models = [
    { "make": "alfaRomeo", "value": "4cSpider",  "text": "4C Spider" },
    { "make": "alfaRomeo", "value": "4c",        "text": "4C" },
    { "make": "alfaRomeo", "value": "giulQuad",  "text": "Giulietta Quadrifoglio Verde" },
    { "make": "alfaRomeo", "value": "giulietta", "text": "Giulietta" },
    { "make": "alfaRomeo", "value": "mitoQuad",  "text": "MiTo Quadrifoglio" },
    { "make": "alfaRomeo", "value": "mito",      "text": "MiTo" },
    { "make": "ford",      "value": "focus",     "text": "Focus" },
    { "make": "ford",      "value": "f350",      "text": "F-350" }
];


$('#make').change(function () {
    var select = $("#model");
    var make = $(this).val();

    //Clear all options
    select.find('option').remove();

    //add relevant options
    for (var i=0; i < models.length; i++) {
        if (models[i].make == make)
            $("<option />")
            .attr("value", models[i].value)
            .text(models[i].text)
            .appendTo(select);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is probably the best way to handle the problem.